# Maximize CPU and memory usage when using gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, linux, optimization

I'm using gdalwarp to clip and warp a large (but not huge) GeoTIFF (6.2 GB total size). The GDAL command I am using is:

`gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 80% -wm 80% -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0" -tr 10 10 -r bilinear -cutline [datasource] -cwhere [expression] -crop_to_cutline -cblend 100 [srcfile] [dstfile]`

I want to make sure I'm fully utilizing all available resources so this goes as fast as possible (hence the `--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 80% -wm 80% -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS` flags). However, when my CPU usage never goes above 100% (i.e.  that is only 1 of 8 cores is being used) and memory usage is < 1 GB. Is there any way I can speed up this process?

Comment: Trying to maximize memory usage is not necessarily a good strategy. After all, each pixel gets warped only once. High CPU is good if CPU is doing something useful. Tiled input and output formats are easier for warping. Add `- co TILED=YES` into the output and check with gdalinfo if source file is tiled.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this isn't really possible with the current gdalwarp algorithms without running parallel processes

Depending on your process it may be faster to split up the tiff into separate tiles and process in parallel, I'm not sure about your set up but if you have QGIS here are some snippets of PyQGIS code that may assist

When I ran a process like this (but with 4 tasks, not 2 as below) it used up much more CPU and used the entirety of my memory, because of multiple cmd windows being open

No idea if this is actually faster but it definitely uses more resources

```py
gdalOptionsSpeed = '-co COMPRESS=ZSTD -co PREDICTOR=1 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=IF_SAFER -co TILED=YES -co ZSTD_LEVEL=1 -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 49% -wm 49% -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -overwrite'
gdalOptionsFinal = '-co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=IF_SAFER -co TILED=YES -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 80% -wm 80% -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -overwrite'
    
def cmdOne(task):
    try:
        cmd = 'gdalwarp -of GTiff ' + gdalOptionsSpeed + ' -dstalpha "' + aiOutputRefClipDirectory1 + '**.tif" "' + stagingImageDir + outImageName + 'Staging1.tif" & timeout 5'
        os.system(cmd)
    except BaseException as e:
        print (e)

cmdTask1 = QgsTask.fromFunction('CmdProcess', cmdOne)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(cmdTask1)

def cmdTwo(task):
    try:
        cmd = 'gdalwarp -of GTiff ' + gdalOptionsSpeed + ' -dstalpha "' + aiOutputRefClipDirectory2 + '**.tif" "' + stagingImageDir + outImageName + 'Staging2.tif" & timeout 5'
        os.system(cmd)
    except BaseException as e:
        print (e)

cmdTask2 = QgsTask.fromFunction('CmdProcess2', cmdTwo)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(cmdTask2)

"""
#######################################################################
"""

try:
    cmdTask1.waitForFinished(timeout = 20000000)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)     
try:
    cmdTask2.waitForFinished(timeout = 20000000)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)


#Final task
cmd = 'gdalwarp -of GTiff ' + gdalOptionsFinal + ' "' + stagingImageDir + '**.tif" "' + finalImageDir + outImageName + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") + '.tif" & timeout 5'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Did a quick bit of testing for a regular image export, it seems that for a test where I was mosaicking 8 images together, any assignment of more memory slowed things down? This worked best: '-co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS co BIGTIFF=IF_SAFER -co TILED=YES -multi --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -overwrite'

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this old question! Looking forward to digging into your answer